# How to make it so when connecting a new device to pi blue tooth speaker you don't have to type anything

Tags: audio, bluetooth

I have recently set my Pi up as a Bluetooth speaker. But when I connect a new device to it I have to go on to my Pi, pair and authorize services. This is very impractical for what I plan to do with my Pi (a portable speaker). Is there any way I can make it so I don't have to sign into my Pi and it just accepts everything by default?

Also I am using a Pi 3 with the inbuilt Bluetooth.

Comment: You do realize that this presents a security threat?

Comment: yes i do but i dont have anything of worth on the pi and it will only be running when i am using it, which will be rarely

Comment: What about what is on the rest of your network, and any sites you visit in your browser?

Comment: when it's done it will not be connected to a network

Comment: I agree with Steve, your idea is dangerous for reasons I don't think you fully understand. How about adding a button to the RPi that accepts the next connection provided it's made within 30 seconds (or something else)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-wireless-networking-41/setting-up-bluez-with-a-passkey-pin-to-be-used-as-headset-for-iphone-816003/) seems to describe a similar setup. Basically, you'll have to do the following:

Configure your RPi as a speaker:

```
hciconfig hci0 piscan
hciconfig hci0 sspmode 1
hciconfig hci0 name BT_Speaker
```

Run the pairing agent with a pin of your choice:

```
bluetooth-agent 1234
```

Your RPi will then request any new device for a pin `1234` in order to pair, but there will be no pin to enter on RPi itself.

Alternatively, if you don't want any pin at all, check out [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115896/disable-pin-request-for-pairing-on-raspbian). You'll have to edit `bluez-simple-agent` to set pairing method to `NoInputNoOutput`. You'll have to check whether that will be acceptable for the devices you want to pair.